# IAP Service is not initialized: IStoreListener without MonoBehaviour, possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

how can I get the call to `OnInitialized(Purchasing.IStoreController controller, Purchasing.IExtensionProvider extensions) form IStoreListener` without using a Monobehaviour?

Do I've to make my class `public class IapManager : IStoreListener` to a Monobehaviour or is there a better way to register my class somewhere to get the needed calls.

For me, a Monobehaviour doesn't make much sense here. I would very much appreciate an answer with a better solution. Thank you!

Comment: as far as I understand the docs it would have to be a MonoBehaviour. What speaks against it? I mean anyway in the end I guess some MonoBehaviour stores the reference to the `IaPManager`, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I had the call from Unity Purchasing.Initialize(..); overlooked. I thought somewhere is just looking for a component with the interface IStoreListener and then initialize it if there exits one. but luckily the architecture is good anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute` on a static class (doesn't have to be MonoBehaviour)

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html

Comment: But `InitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute` is implemented in UnityEditor and not in UnityEngine

Comment: You are correct, my mistake. I meant RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute. Editted my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had the call from Unity `Purchasing.Initialize(..);` overlooked. I thought somewhere a class from Unity is just looking for a component with the interface IStoreListener (for example: `FindObjectsOfType<IStoreListener >();`and then initialize it.
But luckily the architecture is good anyway and everything works fine without a MonoBehaviour.